# SQL database design foreign key

Tags: jquery, mysql, database-design

Hello i am fairly new to databases and have a design question / problem.

I have a table called products which has the following columns and stores information about a product and three relatively large pictures of the article alongside with it.

```
id = primary key
product_id = int
product_name = varchar
product_description = text 
image1_name = varchar
image1_data = longblob
image2_name = varchar
image2_data = longblob
image3_name = varchar
image3_data = longblob
```

I also have a jquery animated slideshow element on my website, which is supposed to display five pictures which i as the admin of the site can chose and display the product name with it.

For this purpose I thought about creating a second table slideshow which holds no more than five entries and essentially points to either imagedata1, imagedata2 or imagedata3 and the product_name of products

```
id = primary key
product_name = product.product_name
imagedata = imagedata 1 or 2 or 3
```

As far as I know there are no pointers in SQL. How is this achievable ? Do I have to change my design ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two methodology for such cases.

1. 1nF
2. 3nf or BCNF

1NF :

one table same as yours: 
Just add one column stating slider count for your product.
5 columns for your imagename.
if you want to store image in database then 5 more colums with blob datatype

3 NF:

1st table with product details

```
 product_id = int (primary key)
 product_name = varchar
 product_description = text
```

2nd table with image information

```
id (primarykey)
 product_id (foreign key)
 slider_image_name varchar
 image_sequence int
 imagedata (only if you want to store image in database)
 image_status (tinyint) [1 for active o for inactive]
```

I prefers to keep images in file format and store complete url to load in database.
Incase you also want to load it via url then you can remove imagedata column

3NF or BCNF form is more prefred

Comment: i think this answer makes the most sense, as it takes into consideration that one product has many Images and it is neccessary to have a boolean variable to denote whether or not this image is part of the slideshow / in what sequence it appears.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is you would have two tables.

```
-- product table --
id = primary key
product_id = int
product_name = varchar
product_description = text 

-- product_image_table --
id = primary key
product_table_id = {product table id}
image_name = varchar
image_data = longblob
```

Then on your new table that you were thinking about would reference records in the product_image_table and possibly the product table.  The benifit with this is your not constrained to how many images can be stored on the product table and you don't have to add more columns if you need to store more, and you don't have empty cells for products that have less than your max number of images.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about it, currently you need 3 images in a slide show for a product, however, tomorrow you might need 1 or you might need 5 for a specific product, so clearly your design isn't flexible enough or overly-flexible.

So... what's the correct model here?

[One-To-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model))

this will allow you most flexibility w/o any redundant columns

think of it as a product **has many** images, and how will you model that?

your current product table will have no knowledge of the images and you'll add a new table, called `product_images`

```
product_images
id | int
product_id | int
image_url | varchar
```

so if you have a product, you could do another query for it's images

```
SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE product_id = ?
```

or to receive all images of certain products

```
SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE product_id IN (?)
```

**Extra**: let's say you have many models requiring image capabilities, you could create a `polymorphic table` named `images`, a table which not only contains a reference_id, but an extra column which also has a reference_type

```
images
id | int
reference_id | int
reference_type | varchar
image_url | varchar
```

And now, if you have a product, you could do a query for it's images

```
SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE reference_id = ? and reference_type = 'product'
```

or to receive all images of certain products

```
SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE reference_id IN (?) AND reference_type = 'product'
```

and of course, you could query for another reference_type as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Almost invariably, you want to properly normalize the design. The purpose of normalization is to minimize anomalous data from entering the database. You want to make it impossible, for example, to insert a fourth row where only three are allowed. Creating three pairs of columns in the row definition also accomplishes that, but at the cost of extra unused space and severe restriction of future enhancements.

There has always been a limitation with relational cardinality. We can natively define a 1-to-many relationship (actually: 1 to zero or more), but we cannot natively define a 1-to-3 relationship (1 to zero or more up to three).

So we do what we always do when we must implement a feature outside of native relational definitions: we cheat.

There are many ways to cheat here with, of course, pros and cons to each one. My favorite is to go ahead and create a 1-m table with a little additional constraint:

```
create table ProductImages(
    ProdID   int not null,
    Card     tinyint not null,
    Name     varchar not null,
    Image    longblob not null,
    constraint PK_ProductImages primary key( ProdID, Card ),
    constraint CK_CardRange check( Card between 1 and 3 ),
    constraint FK_ProdImageProd foreign key( ProdID )
        references Products( ID )
);
```

The pros here are that you get what you want, namely zero, 1, 2 or 3 images associated with any particular product.

The cons are

- You have to programmatically determine the cardinality value: 1, 2 or 3. This cannot be automatically generated.
- The cardinality values must be between 1 and 3, but they can be inserted in any order or there could be missing values.

As cons go, these are easily handled in app code. And you retain all the benefits of normalization.